# WinDivert issue - redirecting DNS back to self on windows

Tags: c, windows, networking, dns, packet

I was looking at basil00's torwall, and for fun was trying to pare it down to just intercept DNS. (provide an answer back to myself of 127.0.0.1 for webfiltering purposes, learning project)

however, at this point, I have it hijacking the dns packet, but it does not return a correct address. for every "blocked" domain, it's different.

for example, I put cbc.ca in my hosts.deny file (blacklist), and it returns an address of 0.4.114.2

then blacklisting slashdot, it will return 0.4.0.1

this has been quite confusing and frustrating, and after three days of research, I am out of ideas.

Here is the code to the redirect portion of my program, which seems to be where things go awry.
(note some of the comments will be goofy as I was hacking down a program for a different purpose and haven't cleaned it up yet)

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include "windivert.h"

#include "domain.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "redirect.h"

#define MAX_PACKET          4096
#define NUM_WORKERS         4

// DNS headers
#define DNS_MAX_NAME    254
struct dnshdr
{
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t options;
    uint16_t qdcount;
    uint16_t ancount;
    uint16_t nscount;
    uint16_t arcount;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

struct dnsq
{
    uint16_t type;
    uint16_t class;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

struct dnsa
{
    uint16_t name;
    uint16_t type;
    uint16_t class;
    uint32_t ttl;
    uint16_t length;
    uint32_t addr;
} __attribute__((__packed__));


static DWORD redirect_worker(LPVOID arg);
static int handle_dns(HANDLE handle, PWINDIVERT_ADDRESS addr,
    PWINDIVERT_IPHDR iphdr, PWINDIVERT_UDPHDR udphdr, char *data,
    size_t data_len);


// State:
static bool redirect_on = false;
static HANDLE handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
static HANDLE workers[NUM_WORKERS] = {NULL};    // Worker threads



// Send a packet asynchronously:
static void send_packet(HANDLE handle, void *packet, size_t packet_len,
    PWINDIVERT_ADDRESS addr)
{
    addr->Direction = WINDIVERT_DIRECTION_INBOUND;
    WinDivertHelperCalcChecksums(packet, packet_len, 0);
    if (!WinDivertSend(handle, packet, packet_len, addr, NULL))
        debug("Send packet failed (err=%d)\n", (int)GetLastError());
}


// Start traffic redirect through Tor:
extern void redirect_start(void)
{
    debug("DNS divert START\n");

    if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    handle = WinDivertOpen(
        "outbound and udp.DstPort == 53 or inbound and udp.DstPort = 53", 0, 0, 0);



    // Launch threads:
    redirect_on = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++)
    {
        workers[i] = CreateThread(NULL, MAX_PACKET*3,
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)redirect_worker, (LPVOID)handle, 0, NULL);
        if (workers[i] == NULL)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

// Stop traffic redirect through Tor:
extern void redirect_stop(void)
{
    debug("DNS divert STOP\n");

    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    // Close the WinDivert handle; will cause the workers to exit.
    redirect_on = false;
    if (!WinDivertClose(handle))
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(workers[i], INFINITE);
        workers[i] = NULL;
    }

}

// Redirect worker thread:
static DWORD redirect_worker(LPVOID arg)
{
    HANDLE handle = (HANDLE)arg;

    // Packet processing loop:
    char packet[MAX_PACKET];
    UINT packet_len;
    WINDIVERT_ADDRESS addr;

    while (redirect_on)
    {
        if (!WinDivertRecv(handle, packet, sizeof(packet), &addr, &packet_len))
        {
            // Silently ignore any error.
            continue;
        }

        PWINDIVERT_IPHDR iphdr = NULL;
        PWINDIVERT_TCPHDR tcphdr = NULL;
        PWINDIVERT_UDPHDR udphdr = NULL;
        PVOID data = NULL;
        UINT data_len;
        WinDivertHelperParsePacket(packet, packet_len, &iphdr, NULL, NULL,
            NULL, &tcphdr, &udphdr, &data, &data_len);

        int dnshandle = 0;
        if (udphdr != NULL && ntohs(udphdr->DstPort) == 53)
            dnshandle = handle_dns(handle, &addr, iphdr, udphdr, data, data_len);


        if(dnshandle != 1)
        {
            if (!WinDivertSend(handle, packet, packet_len, &addr, NULL))
            {


            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}



// Handle DNS requests.
// NOTES:
// - If anything goes wrong, we simply drop the packet without error.
// - An alternative approach would be to let Tor resolve the address, however,
//   this would be slow.
static int handle_dns(HANDLE handle, PWINDIVERT_ADDRESS addr,
    PWINDIVERT_IPHDR iphdr, PWINDIVERT_UDPHDR udphdr, char *data,
    size_t data_len)
{

    struct dnshdr *dnshdr = (struct dnshdr *)data;
    data += sizeof(struct dnshdr);
    data_len -= sizeof(struct dnshdr);

    char name[DNS_MAX_NAME + 8];            // 8 bytes extra.
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < data_len && data[i] != 0)
    {
        size_t len = data[i];
        if (i + len >= DNS_MAX_NAME)
            return -1;
        name[i++] = '.';
        for (size_t j = 0; j < len; j++, i++)
            name[i] = data[i];
    }

    name[i++] = '\0';

    // Generate a fake IP address and associate it with this domain name:
    uint32_t fake_addr = domain_lookup_addr(name);
    if (fake_addr == 0)
    {

        // This domain is blocked; so ignore the request.
        // Construct a query response:
    size_t len = sizeof(struct dnshdr) + data_len + sizeof(struct dnsa);
    if (len > 512)                          // Max DNS packet size.
        return -1;
    len += sizeof(WINDIVERT_IPHDR) + sizeof(WINDIVERT_UDPHDR) + len;

    char buf[len + 8];                      // 8 bytes extra.
    PWINDIVERT_IPHDR riphdr = (PWINDIVERT_IPHDR)buf;
    PWINDIVERT_UDPHDR rudphdr = (PWINDIVERT_UDPHDR)(riphdr + 1);
    struct dnshdr *rdnshdr = (struct dnshdr *)(rudphdr + 1);
    char *rdata = (char *)(rdnshdr + 1);


    UINT local_ip;
    DivertHelperParseIPv4Address("127.0.0.1",&local_ip);

    memset(riphdr, 0, sizeof(WINDIVERT_IPHDR));
    riphdr->Version   = 4;
    riphdr->HdrLength = sizeof(WINDIVERT_IPHDR) / sizeof(uint32_t);
    riphdr->Length    = htons(len);
    riphdr->Id        = htons(0xF00D);
    WINDIVERT_IPHDR_SET_DF(riphdr, 1);
    riphdr->TTL       = 64;
    riphdr->Protocol  = IPPROTO_UDP;
    riphdr->SrcAddr   = iphdr->DstAddr;
    riphdr->DstAddr   = iphdr->SrcAddr;

    memset(rudphdr, 0, sizeof(WINDIVERT_UDPHDR));
    rudphdr->SrcPort  = htons(53);          // DNS
    rudphdr->DstPort  = udphdr->SrcPort;
    rudphdr->Length   = htons(len - sizeof(WINDIVERT_IPHDR));

    rdnshdr->id = dnshdr->id;
    rdnshdr->options = htons(0x8180);       // Standard DNS response.
    rdnshdr->qdcount = htons(0x0001);
    rdnshdr->ancount = htons(0x0001);
    rdnshdr->nscount = 0;
    rdnshdr->arcount = 0;

    memcpy(rdata, data, data_len);
    struct dnsa *rdnsa = (struct dnsa *)(rdata + data_len);
    rdnsa->name   = htons(0xC00C);
    rdnsa->type   = htons(0x0001);          // (A)
    rdnsa->class  = htons(0x0001);          // (IN)
    rdnsa->ttl    = htonl(0x00000258) ;              // 1 second
    rdnsa->length = htons(0x0004);
    rdnsa->addr   = htonl(local_ip);       // Fake address

    send_packet(handle, &buf, len, addr);



    debug("address: %u\n",addr->Direction);
    debug("Intercept DNS %s\n", (name[0] == '.'? name+1: name));
    return 1;
    }
    // Re-inject the matching packet.


    /*
    /
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the domain lookup side of it (mostly just hacked down to try to get the results I want:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "domain.h"
#include "main.h"

#define RATE_LIMIT                  8000

#define rand16()                    \
    (rand() & 0xFF) | ((rand() & 0xFF) << 8)

// Domain blacklist:
struct blacklist
{
    size_t size;
    size_t len;
    char **names;
};
static struct blacklist *blacklist = NULL;

// State:
static struct name *names[UINT16_MAX] = {NULL};

static HANDLE names_lock = NULL;

// Prototypes:
static struct blacklist *domain_blacklist_read(const char *filename);
static bool domain_blacklist_lookup(struct blacklist *blacklist,
    const char *name);
static int __cdecl domain_blacklist_compare_0(const void *x, const void *y);
static int domain_blacklist_compare(const char *name0, size_t len,
    const char *name1);



// Initialize this module:
extern void domain_init(void)
{
    // Load the domain blacklist.
    blacklist = domain_blacklist_read("hosts.deny");

}

// Lookup an address given a domain name.  If the name does not exist then
// create one.
extern uint32_t domain_lookup_addr(const char *name0)
{
    if (name0[0] == '.')
        name0++;

    if (domain_blacklist_lookup(blacklist, name0))
    {
        debug("Block %s\n", name0);

        return 0;       // Blocked!
    }
    return;
}



// Read the blacklist file:
static struct blacklist *domain_blacklist_read(const char *filename)
{
    struct blacklist *blacklist =
        (struct blacklist *)malloc(sizeof(struct blacklist));
    if (blacklist == NULL)
    {

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    blacklist->size = 0;
    blacklist->len = 0;
    blacklist->names = NULL;

    FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (stream == NULL)
    {
        return blacklist;
    }

    // Read blocked domains:
    int c;
    char buf[256];
    while (true)
    {
        while (isspace(c = getc(stream)))
            ;
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        if (c == '#')
        {
            while ((c = getc(stream)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;
            continue;
        }
        size_t i = 0;
        while (i < sizeof(buf)-1 && (c == '-' || c == '.' || isalnum(c)))
        {
            buf[i++] = c;
            c = getc(stream);
        }
        if (i >= sizeof(buf)-1 || !isspace(c))
        {

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        buf[i] = '\0';
        if (blacklist->len >= blacklist->size)
        {
            blacklist->size = (blacklist->size == 0? 32: 2 * blacklist->size);
            blacklist->names = (char **)realloc(blacklist->names,
                blacklist->size * sizeof(char *));
            if (blacklist->names == NULL)
            {

                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        size_t size = (i+1) * sizeof(char);
        char *name = (char *)malloc(size);
        if (name == NULL)
        {

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
            name[j] = buf[i - 1 - j];
        name[i] = '\0';
        blacklist->names[blacklist->len++] = name;
    }

    fclose(stream);

    qsort(blacklist->names, blacklist->len, sizeof(char *),
        domain_blacklist_compare_0);
    return blacklist;
}

// Check if a domain matches the blacklist or not:
static bool domain_blacklist_lookup(struct blacklist *blacklist,
    const char *name)
{
    if (blacklist->len == 0)
        return false;

    size_t len = strlen(name);
    ssize_t lo = 0, hi = blacklist->len-1;
    while (lo <= hi)
    {
        ssize_t mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        int cmp = domain_blacklist_compare(name, len, blacklist->names[mid]);
        if (cmp > 0)
            hi = mid-1;
        else if (cmp < 0)
            lo = mid+1;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Domain compare function(s):
static int __cdecl domain_blacklist_compare_0(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    const char *name0 = *(const char **)x;
    const char *name1 = *(const char **)y;
    return strcmp(name0, name1);
}
static int domain_blacklist_compare(const char *name0, size_t len,
    const char *name1)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    ssize_t j = (ssize_t)len - 1;
    for (; j >= 0 && name1[i] != '\0'; i++, j--)
    {
        int cmp = (int)name1[i] - (int)name0[j];
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
    }
    if (j < 0 && name1[i] != '\0')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

any assistance is appreciated.

Also, I have uploaded the code to: [Github](https://github.com/jtokarchuk/torwall-wthack/tree/master)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's one of two things going on here. You're reading and writing DNS packets incorrectly, and or you're failing to convert the addresses to or from host to network order before working with them.

I'm going to bet on you reading and writing DNS packets incorrectly. I've implemented my own filtering systems using WinDivert where I was hijacking and passing all DNS traffic through my own local DNS server and I've seen these fudged addresses come out exactly as the results you're getting when I was parsing and writing DNS packets incorrectly.

The bad news is, <strike>I can't point you to a full DNS library in C/C++ as I know of none that actually make the job easier</strike> (maybe, see edits). I personally had my diversion code written in C++ with WinDivert and then use Arsoft.Tools.Net C# DNS library for actually running a local DNS server and manipulating DNS responses.

There is one project in C++ that calls itself boost::net::dns because I think the writer was hoping it would be part of boost, which it isn't and probably won't be. Avoid this library as the internal mechanism for parsing and storing multiple A Records is bugged out and broken and you'll get the same wacky results you're getting here. I tried to work with him to get it fixed but, he was only interested in blaming my code.

I'll have a gander again and update my answer if I can find a decent lib for working with DNS packets in C++. Don't try to do it yourself, we're talking about entire protocols with entire books of RFC's to do this properly yourself.

**Update**

As promised, here are some results from my search:

Mozilla Necko (Formerly Netlib)
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/

C-Ares:
https://github.com/bagder/c-ares

A list of alternative libraries C-Ares compiled:
http://c-ares.haxx.se/otherlibs.html

Also, it is linux specific but pretty clean code. You might be able to pilfer through libcrafter's DNS classes and move them to your own project.

https://github.com/pellegre/libcrafter/blob/master/libcrafter/crafter/Protocols/DNS.h

Again, unless your "learning project" is understanding and recreating one of the foundational pillars of the internet, don't implement this yourself. Try and use one of the previously listed libraries to handle your DNS packets.